# Excel macro generate a report based on raw datas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros

I am currently working on a macro for creating a report of students score and show a percentage at the end of each student.

[image]

I think the picture is self-explanatory. I have data of students like shown on the left-hand side and I want a report like that on the right.
I have been able to create macro for 1 student and rerun each time for each student but I do not know how to make reports for all students at once and stop when all students are done.

The following code is for making new line everytime a new student name occurs:

```
Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer
Dim oRng As Range

Set oRng = Range("A4")

iRow = oRng.Row
iCol = oRng.Column

Do
'
If Cells(iRow + 1, iCol) <> Cells(iRow, iCol) Then
    Cells(iRow + 1, iCol).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    iRow = iRow + 2


Else
    iRow = iRow + 1
End If
'
Loop While Not Cells(iRow, iCol).Text = ""
```

But I do not know where to input the code for percentage calculation.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(R[-3]C+R[-2]C+R[-1]C)/COUNT(R[-3]C:R[-1]C)"
```

I know the it is pretty simple to calculate but I do not know how to loop it.
I can merge the cells and create a box for cells. 
I do not know if I am doing it correctly. But if there is simple way to make this happen then please let me know. I think I am taking a long route but I am a beginner in this.
And where should I input the merging code so that the name of the person merges.

Please let me know if anything is not clear.

Thank you in advance.

*P.S. I am not a teacher. I just want to create a report like this*

Comment: "working on a macro" means you already have started , have code to share and specific questions, please ad them to your question. Questions asking for entire solutions are off-topic here.

Comment: Since you have already written VBA script so better post here, will help us to suggest the modifications.

Comment: I can suggest you VBA (Macro) to merge Column of duplicate Name, then after you need to either use your part of  VBA for subtotal or manually do it,,.

Comment: Where do the percentages come from in the output? How come A has 65 in Physics and 75 in Biology?

Comment: Sorry, the data are pretty mixed up but I think they are not that important. The numbers can be any. I have created a new sheet for my results part. I have written the code to copy necessary data to results sheet. They will be copied in assigned cells and new lines are inputted accordingly. And then percentage is calculated on those empty cells. Adding % to the adjacent cells is not a problem.

Comment: The numbers in your image are a bit confusing. I'm assuming the ones on the left should actually match the ones on the right?

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using a Pivot Table? This is exactly what they do.

Comment: Greg, yes they should be matching. It got mixed up. Freeman, My actual data is different and much complicated but I wanted to know the general idea. And I cannot use pivot table for that. I haven't thought about it till you told me but no I cannot use it.

Answer (score 1):

You want to:

1. Insert a row below each student name
2. Merge student name cells (I'm assuming that's what the letters represent)
3. Add borders, including thicker borders for the student
4. Calculate an average for each student

Here's a solution:

```
Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer
Dim oRng As Range
Dim nRng As Range
Dim persRng As Range
Dim avgRng As Range

Set oRng = Range("A4")

iRow = oRng.Row
iCol = oRng.Column

Do

    If Cells(iRow + 1, iCol) <> Cells(iRow, iCol) Then
        ' Insert row below student name
        Cells(iRow + 1, iCol).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        ' merge name cells
        Set nRng = Range(Cells(iRow + 1, iCol), Cells(iRow - 2, iCol))
        With nRng
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            .Merge
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
            .Font.Bold = True
        End With
        ' Add borders
        Set persRng = Range(Cells(iRow + 1, iCol), Cells(iRow - 2, iCol + 2))
        With persRng.Borders
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Color = vbBlack
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        ' Thick border around average cells
        Set avgRng = Range(Cells(iRow + 1, iCol + 1), Cells(iRow + 1, iCol + 2))
        avgRng.BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlMedium, Color:=vbBlack
        ' Add percent sign and calculate average
        Cells(iRow + 1, iCol + 1).Value = "%"
        Cells(iRow + 1, iCol + 2) _
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=(R[-3]C+R[-2]C+R[-1]C)/COUNT(R[-3]C:R[-1]C)"
        Cells(iRow + 1, iCol + 2).Font.Bold = True
        iRow = iRow + 2


    Else
        iRow = iRow + 1
    End If

Loop While Not Cells(iRow, iCol).Text = ""
```

Comment: I am very new to coding works. Your code will take a time for me to understand how they are working. I will get back here later after done but in the meantime, thank you very much for this.

Comment: **# Greg,** you deserve  perfect 10. It's working nicely.

Comment: I still have some issues. I want to trim down because my code is very long and confusing. So, is there a way to  shorten the text insertion code and setting column width code.

Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 2
Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 10
Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 10
Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "NAME"
Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "SUBJECT"
Range("C2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Score"
Is there a way to solve this in a single line instead of doing it for every single line one at a time.

Comment: Set your column widths at the very beginning. There's no reason to do it more than once. As for the rest, I'm not sure what you're asking. This answer covers your original question. If there's more you're uncertain about, why don't you post a new question and post a link to it here. For starters, I will tell you that 1. You almost never need to select a cell in VBA (in fact it's very inefficient to do so), and 2. Don't use FormulaR1C1 unless you need it (to set a range-relative formula). Instead, set the value of a cell directly: `Range("A1").value = "NAME"`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It is helpful. Here is my question in detail. 
https://superuser.com/questions/1328173/text-input-and-column-width-change-for-multiple-cell-and-columns-respectively-at

Answer (score 0):

I have modified a little to the above code so that now I can have multiple subjects but I do not know how to modify the formula to do that.

```
Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer, nRow As Integer, mRow As Integer
Dim oRng As Range
Dim nRng As Range
Dim persRng As Range
Dim avgRng As Range

Set oRng = Range("A4")

iRow = oRng.Row
iCol = oRng.Column
nRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A12"), "a")
mRow = nRow - 1

Do

    If Cells(iRow + 1, iCol) <> Cells(iRow, iCol) Then
        ' Insert row below student name
        Cells(iRow + 1, iCol).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        ' merge name cells
        Set nRng = Range(Cells(iRow + 1, iCol), Cells(iRow - mRow, iCol))
        With nRng
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            .Merge
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
            .Font.Bold = True
        End With
        ' Add borders
        Set persRng = Range(Cells(iRow + 1, iCol), Cells(iRow - mRow, iCol + 2))
        With persRng.Borders
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Color = vbBlack
            .Weight = xlThin

        End With
        ' Thick border around average cells
        Set avgRng = Range(Cells(iRow + 1, iCol + 1), Cells(iRow + 1, iCol + 2))
        avgRng.BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlMedium, Color:=vbBlack
        ' Add percent sign and calculate average
        Cells(iRow + 1, iCol + 1).Value = "%"
        Cells(iRow + 1, iCol + 2) _
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-5]C:R[-1]C)/COUNT(R[-5]C:R[-1]C)"
        Cells(iRow + 1, iCol + 2).Font.Bold = True
        iRow = iRow + mRow


    Else
        iRow = iRow + 1
    End If

Loop While Not Cells(iRow, iCol).Text = ""
```

Up to this one, it is fine. But I  cannot get the average of subjects if it is anything other than 5.
I tried to change the integer value but it does not seem to work.

```
Cells(iRow + 1, iCol + 2) _
                .FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-nRow]C:R[-1]C)/COUNT(R[-nRow]C:R[-1]C)"
```

How can I do that? Do I need to create another loop for this?

Comment: Another problem with this is that `nRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A12"), "a")
mRow = nRow - 1` only work if the name of the first person is "a". I think it would be better if the function chooses the repetition in the name of the subject for do the loop.

Comment: I tried to input the message box so that it will take the value but it is still not working.  `myNum = Application.InputBox("Enter the number of subjects")`